# Python3 won't find a module listed in pip3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, plotly-dash

I installed dash with pip3, all worked well and showed in the "pip3 list" command.

Nevertheless,when I import it in my script and run my script, I get this error:

```
 File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
   import dash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash'
```

Did that happen to anyone ?

(fyi: running it on mint)

Comment: Are you sure that `pip3` corresponds to the Python interpreter you're running? Are you in a virtualenv? Could you compare `which pip3` and `which python` (or whatever binary you use for running the script)?

Comment: l$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.1

How do I change it ?

Comment: So you have a mismatch, `pip3` install packages for python 3.6 but you are apparently using python 3.7. So either you run python 3.6 or you use the `pip` of python 3.7.

Comment: how do I make pip3 install packages for my version of python3 ?

Comment: Well something's gone wrong with your (two) installations of Python. I recommend to clean that up; i.e. find out where they reside and remove / relocate appropriately (check `which ...`). To use the correct `pip` you can check `which python3` and it will point to something like `.../bin/python3`; then you can just use `.../bin/pip`.

Comment: thanks ! I figured out that my python3 version is linked to anaconda,  thus I just need to use pip.  Thanks !

Comment: To remove a package run:- ( for Future reference) 
-   pip uninstall <package name>